# How to get and set multiple value from html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a array list of combining two value from `.productids` this class and `.quantity` this class. I already tried like bellow. But problem with this jquery is the `productids` class value push able to push each `productids` value but for `.quantity` its always pushing first value which is `1` which is like `["47:1","48:1"]` but it should be like that: `["47:1","48:2"]`.

Below is the sample code

```js
$("#CheckOutBtn").on("click", function () {
var paymentMethodId = $("#paymentMethod").val();
var selectAddressId = $("#selectAddress").val();

var data = [];
$(".product-row").find(".productids").each(function () {

var qty = $(".product-row").find(".quantity");

data.push($(this).val() + ":" + qty.val());

});

console.log(data);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="product-row">
    <td class="product-col">
        <figure class="product-image-container">
            <a href="product.html" class="product-image">
                <img src="#" alt="product">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <h2 class="product-title">
            <a href="#">Xiaomi Redmi 9a 2/32 price in bangladesh</a>
        </h2>
    </td>
    <td>৳9999.00</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="productids" value="47"/>
        <input class="vertical-quantity form-control quantity" value="1" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>৳9999</td>
</tr>
<tr class="product-action-row">
    <td colspan="4" class="clearfix">
        <!--<div class="float-left">
                <a href="#" class="btn-move">Move to Wishlist</a>
            </div>-->
        <!-- End .float-left -->

        <div class="float-right">

            <a href="#" title="Remove product" class="btn-remove"><span class="sr-only">Remove</span></a>
        </div><!-- End .float-right -->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="product-row">
    <td class="product-col">
        <figure class="product-image-container">
            <a href="product.html" class="product-image">
                <img src="#" alt="product">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <h2 class="product-title">
            <a href="#">Xiaomi Radmi note 9 4GB/64GB, Price in Bangladesh</a>
        </h2>
    </td>
    <td>৳19999.00</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="productids" value="48"/>
        <input class="vertical-quantity form-control quantity" value="2" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>৳19999</td>
</tr>
<tr class="product-action-row">
    <td colspan="4" class="clearfix">
        <!--<div class="float-left">
                <a href="#" class="btn-move">Move to Wishlist</a>
            </div>-->
        <!-- End .float-left -->

        <div class="float-right">

            <a href="#" title="Remove product" class="btn-remove"><span class="sr-only">Remove</span></a>
        </div><!-- End .float-right -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That should be a `.map()` instead of an `.each()` + `.push()`

Comment: `$(".product-row").find(".quantity");` selects every element with a `.quantity` class that is a child of any element with a `.product-row` class. You only want the `.quantity` of the current `.product-row`, also known as `this`

Comment: @Andreas how to implement it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping each of product-row and get the two values?

```
$("#CheckOutBtn").on("click", function() {
    var paymentMethodId = $("#paymentMethod").val();
    var selectAddressId = $("#selectAddress").val();

    var data = [];
    $(".product-row").each(function() {
        var pid = $(this).find(".productids").val();
        var qty = $(this).find(".quantity").val();

        data.push(pid + ":" + qty);
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Why do you create twice as much jQuery objects as necessary? Store `$(this)` in a variable and use that to get the values.